# Change BackColor in Datagrid cell Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating Flex application.
When enter data in data grid cell that time i want to check that cell value is less then 20 and if it not then change that cell's back color to red.

How to do this??

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150010/change-the-text-color-of-a-datagrid-row-on-particular-condition-in-air-applicatio/6154219#6154219) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6150010/275643):

I would do this in a custom ItemRenderer and set the font color by overriding the `set data` or `updateDisplayList` function.

From [this article](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/formatting-a-flex-datagrid-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer/):

**The application:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/formatting-a-flex-datagrid-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer/ -->
<mx:Application name="DataGridColumn_itemRenderer_test "
        xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            private function price_labelFunc(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String {
                return currencyFormatter.format(item.@price);
            }

            private function price_sortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
                return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(itemA.@price, itemB.@price);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:XML id="itemsXML">
        <items>
            <item name="Item 1" price="1.32" />
            <item name="Item 2" price="-12.23" />
            <item name="Item 3" price="4.96" />
            <item name="Item 4" price="-0.94" />
        </items>
    </mx:XML>

    <mx:Style>
        .centered {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </mx:Style>

    <mx:CurrencyFormatter id="currencyFormatter"
            precision="2"
            useNegativeSign="false" />

    <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{itemsXML.item}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@name"
                    headerText="Name:"
                    headerStyleName="centered" />

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@price"
                    headerText="Price:"
                    textAlign="right"
                    headerStyleName="centered"
                    labelFunction="price_labelFunc"
                    sortCompareFunction="price_sortCompareFunc"
                    itemRenderer="PriceLabel" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

**PriceLabel.as:**

```
/** http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/formatting-a-flex-datagrid-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer/ */
package {
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.*;

    public class PriceLabel extends Label {

        private const POSITIVE_COLOR:uint = 0x000000; // Black
        private const NEGATIVE_COLOR:uint = 0xFF0000; // Red

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            /* Set the font color based on the item price. */
            setStyle("color", (parseFloat(data.@price) <= 0) ? NEGATIVE_COLOR : POSITIVE_COLOR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Brian True, it probably would have been a bit easier but I figured since you had already mentioned itemRenderers, I would suggest a slightly different approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use an itemRenderer for the dataGrid, and using the 'data' variable in the itemRenderer, check what the value is e.g. >20. Then, set the background color of the itemRenderer based on this.

If you dont know about using itemRenderers, do a google search. There are loads of DataGrid itemRenderer examples out there.